# How to get a changeset SQL query using DB Pro for .net and SQl Server when usinga Team build?

Tags: sql, msbuild, scripting, build-automation

I am working on Build Automation via Team Build (TFS 2008). We are using DB Pro with our Web project.

I want to get the **SQL script** for **database change-set** ,(that has occurred till the nightly build), automatically using MSBuild Script . This script has to bundled in a zip file along with Web Application binaries and pages.

**How can i automatically generate Database change-set(changes of tables and data that occurred since last change-set) in the form of a SQL script that can be executed any SQL Server database(SQL Sever 2000 or 2005 at the minimum).**

kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to automate db deployment on specified database, and after that copy the created script to your package (if you're using VS 2008 DB Pro Edition)